# Scala data flow analysis in IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Does it work? The options are greyed out for me, just want to make sure I'm not missing any setting.

[image]

My IDEA version is:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4
Build #IU-163.12024.16, built on January 31, 2017

JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported for Scala at the moment, you can vote for this request:

- [SCL-8555](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8555) "Analyze Dataflow" Doesn't work In Scala